# How to occurrence of specific value in a column in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table like this:

```
   name col2       cnt
    B5  2.00000000  62
    B6  2.00000000  9
    B4  3.00000000  1
    B5  3.00000000  75
    B6  3.00000000  62
    B5  4.00000000  9
    B6  4.00000000  11
    B5  5.00000000  102
    B6  5.00000000  37
```

I want output as : `B4` i.e., all the names where 2.00000000 never occurred in `col2`. How do I do that? I'm using SQL Server.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `EXISTS` and a correlated subquery to check if a value of `2.00000000` exists for a `name`.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
       t1.name
       FROM elbat t1
       WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                                FROM elbat t2
                                WHERE t2.name = t1.name
                                      AND t2.col2 = 2.00000000);
```

(I assumed `2.00000000` is numeric. If it's a string, put single quotes around it.)

Alternatively you can use conditional aggregation to count the occurrences of `2.00000000`. Use a `HAVING` to only keep the rows where this count is `0`.

```
SELECT t1.name
       FROM elbat t1
       GROUP BY t1.name
       HAVING count(CASE
                      WHEN t.col1 = 2.00000000 THEN
                        1
                    END) = 0
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select distinct t1.name
from yourtable t1
where t1.name not in (
    select t2.name
    from yourtable t2
    where t2.col2 = 2.00000000)
```

Answer (score 1):

If `2.00000000` is the minimum possible value, you can do:

```
select name
from t
group by name
where min(col2) > 2.00000000;
```